# How to change value of a column if the column does not have specific text?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table like this:

```
+---------+-------+
| Fruits  | Price |
+---------+-------+
| Apple   | 2.00  |
| Orange  | 3.00  |
| Banana  | 4.00  |
+---------+-------+
```

And if the `Fruits` column does not have `Grapes` then 
how can I return price of 0 
like

```
+---------+-------+
| Fruits  | Price |
+---------+-------+
| Grape   | 0.00  |
+---------+-------+
```

Here's my query

```
Select
    Fruits, 
    Price
From
    Products
```

Comment: You should add all the fruits in this table and add the default value for them as there is no way database can magically insert a row. it can add default values for certain columns if they don't contain a value but if there is no row then there is no way to identify and instead of adding in query (which makes your query complex) you should add them in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would have a table which contains the names of all fruits which you want to appear in your report.  So, something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    p.Fruits,
    COALESCE(p.Price, 0.00) AS Price
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Apple' AS Fruits UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Orange' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Banana' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Grape'
) AS all_fruits
LEFT JOIN Products p
    ON all_fruits.Fruits = p.Fruits;
```

If you only wanted to see fruits which have no match, then you could add the following to the end of the query:

```
WHERE p.Fruits IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select x.*
from (select 'Grapes' as fruit, 0.00 as price) x
where not exists (select 1 from atable t where t.fruit = 'Grapes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is also a anoter way of doing same `Select from the same table` using `NOT IN` and it will return the duplicate value in case of multiple rows in the table, so we can use `DISTINCT` or `LIMIT` in `MYSQL`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'Grapes' AS fruit, 
    0.00 AS price
FROM yourTable
WHERE 'Grapes' NOT IN (fruits)
```

**Note**: It will not return any record if table is blank and I hope in such case returning value also not meaningful but if you still want return one then I must say sorry :) in this case.